# how to Output page hits to a text document

Tags: asp.net, logging

I have an HTML home page. I want to be able to output to a text document on the server every time a person views the page.

I want to out put the IP addrs, Page and Date/Time anyone know an easy way of doing this?

If it has to be done other than html i would prefer to use ASP.

Comment: Classic ASP or ASP.NET? Do you have database, or want just plain text file?

Comment: asp.net and at the moment i think its simpler just in a text file, in future i will look towards a db and then import it

Comment: Good - second question sorry forgot to ask before: any chance to rename the HTML file to have `.aspx` extension or create new page then have the HTML page redirect to it?

Comment: Cheers, see my answer - also updated the question tags to reflect this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rename the page to have `.aspx` extension and add code behind file as well.

Second, add this method to the code behind:

```cs
private void WriteLog()
{
    string currentFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Request.FilePath);
    string logFileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.log.txt", currentFileName, DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy"));
    string logFilePath = Server.MapPath(logFileName);
    string IP = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    string logMessage = string.Format("[{0}] [IP: {1}] [Page: {2}]", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), IP, Request.FilePath);
    File.AppendAllLines(logFilePath, new string[] { logMessage });
}
```

And finally just call the above method from within the `Page_Load` event e.g.

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WriteLog();
}
```

This will create text file with the same name as the `.aspx` (in the same location) plus the current date to avoid clogging the same file with millions of lines, and append one line for each hit.

Edit: this is .NET 4.0 code so you'll have to define this as the target framework in both Visual Studio in case you're using it, and in the IIS configuration. The `web.config` should be updated by the Studio and in case you're not using it, here are the extra lines:

```xml
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I get the following error...'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for 'AppendAllLines'

Comment: hmmm do you know how the web.conf should look like for v4.0?

Answer (score 1):

As @Alp said PHP would be the way to go:

```
  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //gives you the visitor's IP address

  basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]); //gives you the page name

  date();  // gives you the current date
```

Then it would just be a case of running a little script that writes those to a file on each page.

Might be worth looking at [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) - it gives lot's of useful stats about visitors (not 100% you can get individual IP addresses, can anyone clarify this?)

Edit:

ASP.NET

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]; // ip
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]; // page
```

Comment: @Beginner Just seen in your question you'd prefer to use ASP.net if it can't be done in html - I would say this would be overkill considering the hosting costs etc. and most standard hosting packages support php.

Comment: @Beginner Ok, not that up on .net anymore, but added a few things to my answer.

Comment: The current page is `Request.FilePath`

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP for that if your server supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an existing log framework like Log4Net.